# Leaflet layers, check if a feature.properties exist

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have two layers with markers in a leaflet map.
One have a property "rotation", not the other one.
How can I determine if my layer have the property "rotation" or no, in order to be able to set a rotation for my markers I want to rotate ?

I tried but it doesn't works :

```js
if (feature.properties.rotation){
  var rotate = feature.properties.rotation;
  } else if (feature.properties.rotation === undefined){
  var rotate = 0;
  }

style = {
    rotation: rotate
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I fixed it using .hasOwnProperty()

Here is the code :

```js
if (feature.hasOwnProperty('rotation')){
  var rotate = feature.properties.rotation;
  } else {
  var rotate = 0;
  }

style = {
    rotation: rotate
    };
```